# Vue JS 2 Environment Variables to Connect to Docker Containers without Port Binding

Tags: docker, vue.js, vuejs2, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose project that defines a frontend service running a Vue JS application with an NGINX server, and a backend service running a flask API. For development it is easy enough to define an `env.development` with:

```
API_URL="http://localhost:5010"
```

Is there anyway to take advantage of Docker's routing so that I can connect to the service using it's name (as I'm used to doing server-side) so that I can dispense with port binding my backend service to 5010 on my host machine?

something like

```
API_URL="backend:5010"
```

would be ideal, so that I wouldn't have to perform any trickery to get the container's ip. The overall goal would be to isolate the docker stack from the host so that multiple instances could be started without creating port conflicts.

Thank you for any help or insight you can offer.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. When you declare services in docker compose, as long as they are in the same network (which by default is true), then using the service name should work.

Comment: I thought that as well, and have used this method quite a few times. However, there seems to be something odd with vue js environment variables since they are interpreted in the browser. It is unable to connect unless I bind the port in the host, and connect to localhost. I’m wondering if there is some way to proxy the client-side vue through something really small on the nginx side (same container) to the correct containers?

Comment: Oh you're right! We used to have that same problem in my old work since we had several services that were called from the browser. We ended up using: https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy and using custom domains for each application. It's very easy to set up.

Comment: You may be right; that might be the only way to get this done. I was hoping to not have to edit the hosts file.